# How to use components outside of controllers in CakePhp 3?

Tags: class, cakephp, components

I'd like to use a Cakephp 3 component inside a class located in, for example, /src/Classes/Customers.php.
I don't know how to instanciate the compoent.

Answer (score 1):

You are *not* supposed to do that, components are services for the controller layer, and that's where the story ends. It is strongly advised that you do not use framework components outside of their intended purpose, this will just cause trouble at some point!

If you want to share logic between components and other utilities unrelated to controllers, then you should put that logic into for example generic service classes that both your components as well as your other code can utilize.

Comment: That's not the intended answer but thanks. I just can't see anymore those big controller with thousand of lines. That's the same for components.

Comment: Maybe give more detail about what you're trying to accomplish? Because @ndm's answer seems to cover all the bases.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I'd like to remove all my business logic from controllers to  move it into classes.

Comment: That's what components do. But you don't want to put it in components either? CakePHP is just PHP. Put the code in any class and function you want, and follow standard namespacing rules.

Comment: I am in a intermediate solution where I want to migrate my code from components to classes.